# SQL Transformation from rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
ID VALUE BRAND
1 group1 Hollister
1 group2 Express
1 group 3 Persche 
2 Group1 Hollister
3 Group3 Persche
```

and so on. and want to transform to something like this which are unique on ID in sql:

```
ID Hollister Express Persche 
1  Group1   Group2   Group3 
2  Group1   BLANK    Blank 
3  Blank    Blank    Group3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when brand = 'Hollister' then value end) as Hollister,
       max(case when brand = 'Express' then value end) as Express,
       max(case when brand = 'Persche' then value end) as Persche
from table t
group by id;
```

This will produce `NULL`.  If you actually want `''`:

```
select id,
       max(case when brand = 'Hollister' then value else '' end) as Hollister,
       max(case when brand = 'Express' then value else '' end) as Express,
       max(case when brand = 'Persche' then value else '' end) as Persche
from table t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working `PIVOT` option:

```
Select  * 
From 
(
    Select  value, Brand, id
    From    YourTable
) Source
Pivot
(
    Max(value)
    For Brand In ([Hollister],[Express],[Persche])
) P
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table.

here's an example :[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

```
select *
from 
(
  select store, week, xCount
  from yt
) src
pivot
(
  sum(xcount)
  for week in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```